# Clarity or suggestions needed on coding standards for the below scenario

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm trying to improve my site performance, Currently we lazy load the non-critical javascript files after the window load.

Now, I just found that on page load, the execution time of those files hinders the performance score even though they are lazy-loaded.

To overcome this we just modified the tags as below,

Before Modification:

```
<script type=text/javascript>//here js code</script>
```

After Modification:

```
<script type=text/plain>//here js code</script>
```

after window load, we change the type to `type=text/javascript` for proceeding with execution.

And because of this change, the site performance has increased drastically.

So, from the above scenario, I would like to know about opinions and suggestions such that I'm not breaking any coding standards or best practices.

Comment: What do you mean by site performance? The amount of time it takes before the page is useable?

Comment: Yes, @MattEllen.
Additional information, Performance here points to Lighthouse performance metrics for a site.